# Adding new field to solr schema doesn't add it to all documents

Tags: solr, schema

I've added new field

restarted service and rebuilt all indexes. After I do search, not all the documents have this new field in the result xml.
document that has it xml:

```
">"<doc>
">"...
">"<int name="ghost">0</int>
">"...
">"</doc>
```

Out of 100 documents only about 25 have this field added. All other are missing it.

I am completely out of ideas...

Comment: How did the 25 documents get the contents oft the new field?

Comment: how did you rebuilt the indexes? what values are you expecting?